# Is it possible to get from a major airport to Morzine in the ski season using public transport?

Tags: public-transport, france, alps, geneva, skiing

We're planning a ski trip to morzine in the new year but I'd prefer not to rent a car. I could get a transfer but I'm hoping public transport will be more cost effective. So how is the easiest/cheapest way to get to Morzine in the ski season from any major airport?

At the moment I'm thinking about flying into Geneva but that's not booked yet so this is flexible. We will be flying from Manchester (UK) so if not Geneva it must have direct flights from here.

Comment: There is apparently a [public bus option](http://www.sat-annemasse.com/img/os_document/362_fiche_horaire_ligne_91_du_01092016_au_16122016.pdf) but it does not seem particularly convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually work for a chalet company who provide transport from Geneva to Morzine, there are plenty independent bus companies that will take you.

I have found previously that this http://www.morzexpress.com/ is the best option (cost effective way) to get to morzine from geneva.

Comment: Not quite what I was after. I was thinking more public bus, train. But it does seem resonably priced, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with a similar question, there are several small companies that run transfers from GVA to Chamonix, Morzine and all the local ski resorts. These operate mini-buses or even coaches and the prices are in the few-tens-of-euros bracket. There are too many to list but googling "GVA Morzine Transfer" will get you an exhaustive list.

I'm not sure what the motive is for "public" transport... these are public in the sense that anyone can get on them and that you will be seated with other random people. They are also pretty cheap. They are, however, private companies run for profit (then again, so are many "public" transport companies around the world).